# tidyverse in R: Cannot load tidyverse package

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I am using RStudio (R 4.2.1).
I am having trouble loading the tidyverse package. I have already installed the tidyverse package.

Below is the code

```
##...Installing the package "tidyverse"
install.packages("tidyverse")

##...Loading tidyverse.
library("tidyverse")
```

The output of the code above:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/tidyverse_1.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 429021 bytes (418 KB)
downloaded 418 KB

package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpID62r2\downloaded_packages
> ##...Loading tidyverse.
> library("tidyverse")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘cli’ 3.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required
```

I have installed the tidyverse package multiple times and every time I attempt to install the tidyverse package it does not ask for an update. While other packages ask for an update as I attempt to install them for 2nd time.
**The tidyverse package is always installed as a new package and the attempt to load the package keeps giving the same prompt every time.**

Comment: Have you installed Rtools ? And you'll need to update required package such as `cli` until the tidyverse package needs it

Comment: I have installed Rtools. I successfully updated the `cli` package everything in `tidyverse` is working properly now. Thank you so much.